# How to check if textfield has more than one letter in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm working on a text field in Swift and what I'm about to implement is that disabling the navigation button unless there is 0 character in the text field and adding the delete button on the text field if there is more than 1 letter on the text field, like an iOS default calendar app.

The bar button item "Add" is disabled when there is no letter in the title text field.

[image]

Enable the "Add" button and show the delete button when there is 1+ letter in the Title text field.

[image]

I took a look at the text field delegate methods and I think I can implement the one I'm trying to by using shouldChangeCharactersIn method (?)

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    // check if there is a letter in the text field
    // if there is, enable the Add button and show delete icon
    // if there is not, disable the add button and hide the delete icon
    return true
}
```

I was wondering if there are other methods to implement this functionality? I think whenever type / delete a letter on the text field, the function above will be called everytime, so I was wondering if there are other ways to implement this stuff easily.

Comment: Do you want to check a single text field or multiple like if anyone textfield has a single character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
    validateTextField(text:textField.tex)
}
```

your method shouldChangeCharactersIn is not working properly sometimes
so can use this method
make a function that take text and disable and enable nav bar and delete button like

```
func validateTextField(text:String) {
  if text.count > 1 {
    textField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
  } else if text.count <= 1 {
     textField.clearButtonMode = .never
  } else if text.count < 1 {
     navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = .lightGray
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use storyboard approach for particular textfield text count.

```
1.Ctrl + Click on the textfield in interface builder.
```

2. Drag from EditingChanged to inside your view controller class in the assistant view.

[image]

3.Name your function ("textFieldEditingChanged" for example) and click connect.

[image]